# Pass styles property to a Card component of Create View

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

I have an autocomplete component at the bottom of the `Create` view with `TabbedForm`.

Dropdown list is getting hidden as `overflow` of parent `Card` component is set to hidden.

Is there a way to pass a `style` property to a parent `Card` component to override default material-ui `overflow` property?

If no, is there any hack that I can use to achieve this at a render time?

Comment: The solution I currently use is to override on a global level in themes.js, may be there is another way to make it for one particular view/card only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const cardCreateStyles = {
  card: {
    overflow: 'scroll',
    backgroundColor: 'Lavender',
  }
}

const CardCreate = withStyles(cardCreateStyles)(({ classes, ...props }) => (
  <Create classes={classes} {...props} >
  ...
  </Create>
))
```